# How to override mouse event with touch event using javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, mouseevent, touch-event

I'm trying to simulate the touch events in a react.js application. The goal is to trigger touch events instead of mouse ones (i.e. `mouseDown` should trigger `touchStart`, etc.).

The behavior I'm trying to replicate is the same one as when you're using the Chrome dev tool console on mobile view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an event with the class Event. Then you can dispatch the event on a dom element or on window

```js
const clickEvent = new Event('touchStart', {"bubbles":true})
window.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
```

Here is a long article that covers these 2 lines of code: https://medium.com/@gianfranconuschese/simulating-events-with-javascript-c62da15422b2

so basically you could use `window.addEventListener('mouseDown', eventHandler)` where eventHandler would be a function that calls the two lines of code I shared earlier